Mark and find the answer!
The answer to this puzzle is a single word. What word?
 A=10, B=3, C=6, D=1, E=10, F=6, G=2, H=5, I=10, J=3, K=4, L=1, M=10
 N=6, O=8, P=3, Q=10, R=4, S=9, T=1, U=2, V=5, W=2, X=5, Y=2, Z=2
 0=12, 1=9, 2=13, 3=8, 4=10, 5=18, 6=14, 7=16, 8=12, 9=18


   — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — —  
 —
 —
 —
 —
 —
 —
 —
 —
 —
 —
   

Note: It seems hard to solve this without the aid of computer. I tried to do it for a while and made some progress but then I got stuck. For this reason I've added the 'computer-puzzle'-tag.
 Having said that, I wouldn't be surprised if someone in here is able to do it without the aid of computer, using some good logical method, hence the 'logical-deduction'-tag. Anyways, the answer is there. Good luck!

Looks like a puzzle for RobPratt :)

‘integer linear programming’

rot13(Ybbxf yvxr fvzcyl chggvat gur yrggref va nycunorgvpny beqre nybat gur gbc naq ahzoref qbja gur fvqr naq gerngvat ahzoref nf gbgny funqrq fdhnerf va pby/ebj tvirf gbb znal fbyhgvbaf (here's one). Guvf ybbxf yvxr n gvyrcnvag chmmyr, juvpu znxrf zr guvax V'z zvffvat gur pbaarpgrq ertvbaf)

Not an answer. Community wiki to save others time.

The sum total of all the values after the equals sign is 260. The section with dashes has 26 columns and 10 rows, which is 260 cells total. If you line up the 26 letters across all the columns and the 10 digits down all the rows, you end up with this:

From comments on another answer, this is likely a

 • Nonogram that doesn't follow the normal rules (per OP)
 • It is two rows of letters, each 5 blocks tall (per another user)
 • The value for each row/column is the total number of filled cells in that region as opposed to the normal nonogram where you are given several values, each being the length of the contiguous filled cells in that region. (per my own guess)

If you accept that and starting the most basic step of filling in that grid, you can get here pretty easily:

So the part that OP says may need a computer or great ingenuity is figuring out how to fill the rest of the grid to both form letters and satisfy the total number of cells in each row/column.
If it helps anyone, here is the CSV version of that grid
,Value,10,3,6,1,10,6,2,5,10,3,4,1,10,6,8,3,10,4,9,1,2,5,2,5,2,2
Value,,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z
12,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
9,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
13,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
8,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
14,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
16,7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
12,8,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18,9,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,


I'm not convinced that the sum of all the values matching the potential grid area is significant. More critical is that the sum of letter values equals the sum of number values (both being 130); without that, it would be impossible to fill the grid in a way that satisfies all values simultaneously.

@fljx You're right, I thought it could be uniquely solved by computer given the 10's in the column and the fact that we're looking for letters. Wrong assumption by me, so I think I'm gonna delete this question. Not interesting anymore either since you all know what it's all about.

Not a solution so far, just thoughts.

 All I can tell is that its a nonogram, with the answer presumably in Greek characters (due to the image link to the Greek alphabet in the edit tab)

I can't tell whether

 the line break between rows 3 and 4 and the line break between "'computer-puzzle'-tag" and "Having said that"

is intentional or not though.

That was completely unintentional (had a previous idea before posting this puzzle), so just ignore the Greek characters. You're on the right track with rot13(Ababtenz) but it's not exactly the traditional rules of rot(Ababtenz)

Ignore the line breaks. All that matters are the characters and the horizontal lines

Ok, so I think I get the fact that rot13(vg'f gjb yvarf bs svir-gnyy yrggref) but other than that I can't seem to make much more progress. Is the note at the bottom important?

The note is not part of the puzzle, just wanted to say that
